# Running an EMR Spark script, and the Spark UI SQL tab disappears

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr, amazon-emr

When running spark sql jobs on local mode, my Spark UI has a SQL tab.

[image]

When running that same job on AWS EMR, the Spark UI's SQL job is no longer there?

[image]

- I've SSH tunneled
- setup the FoxyProxy settings
- can view the various EMR UI's in the browser
- can view the Spark UI in the browser

is there a code reason why this would not be there in Amazon's EMR version of the Spark UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different UI's for Spark in EMR: 1. the Spark UI, and 2. the Spark History Server.

They look the same, but they are served from different URLs, and one of them continues to be served even after an application completes, as long as the EMR cluster is still up and running.

The history server AFAIK does not have a SQL tab